# build errors with bazel or maven: python is not defined, but why?

Tags: python-2.7, maven, bazel

I'm trying to build (on MacOS) this project https://github.com/jleyba/js-dossier. After installing bazel and executing the build script `./gendossier.sh -r` I get several errors, the first being

> ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'maven':
>
> Error while obtaining the sha256 checksum of v1/https/jcenter.bintray.com/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/maven"): error=2, No such file or directory

I have `alias python=python3` in `.bashrc` so the python command should work, and I confirm this by invoking `python --version` at the end of `.bashrc`.

That directory `/private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/maven` exists, as well as the `aopalliance-1.0.jar` file mentioned in the error message.  Here is proof:

```
[16:45:39 ~/Documents/Programming]$ cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/maven
[16:46:02 /private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/maven]$ ls
coursier    dep-tree.json   v1
[16:46:04 /private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/maven]$ ls -la v1/https/jcenter.bintray.com/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 erikn  wheel  4467 Aug 31  2008 v1/https/jcenter.bintray.com/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
```

How can I begin to figure out this build problem?  I've never used bazel or maven, would it help to learn those first?

Here is the complete set of errors

```
Last login: Thu Mar 16 16:31:58 on ttys006
erikn's .bash_profile is running
erikn's .bashrc is running
cd ~/Documents/Programming
PATH in .bashrc is /Users/erikn/Library/Python/3.9/bin:/Users/erikn/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
Python 3.11.2

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
[16:39:39 ~]$ cd ~/Documents/Programming
[16:39:39 ~/Documents/Programming]$ cd js-dossier
[16:40:08 ~/Documents/Programming/js-dossier]$ ./gendossier.sh -r
erikn's .bashrc is running
PATH in .bashrc is /Users/erikn/Library/Python/3.9/bin:/Users/erikn/Library/Python/3.9/bin:/Users/erikn/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
Python 3.11.2
INFO: Starting clean.
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'maven' which is a coursier_fetch (rule definition at /private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/rules_jvm_external/coursier.bzl:870:18):
 - /private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/rules_jvm_external/defs.bzl:83:5
 - /Users/erikn/Documents/Programming/js-dossier/WORKSPACE:28:1
INFO: Repository 'maven' used the following cache hits instead of downloading the corresponding file.
 * Hash '17f4ff053d0d1dca588afdcc94ca952f7ed85bb03675cd77ec05b7352a832b86' for https://github.com/coursier/coursier/releases/download/v2.0.0-RC3/coursier.jar
If the definition of 'maven' was updated, verify that the hashes were also updated.
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'maven':
   Error while obtaining the sha256 checksum of v1/https/jcenter.bintray.com/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/maven"): error=2, No such file or directory
ERROR: /Users/erikn/Documents/Programming/js-dossier/test/java/com/github/jsdossier/jscomp/BUILD:3:1: //test/java/com/github/jsdossier/jscomp:NodeAliasDetectionTest depends on @maven//:com_google_guava_guava in repository @maven which failed to fetch. no such package '@maven//': Error while obtaining the sha256 checksum of v1/https/jcenter.bintray.com/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/maven"): error=2, No such file or directory
ERROR: /Users/erikn/Documents/Programming/js-dossier/test/java/com/github/jsdossier/jscomp/BUILD:3:1: //test/java/com/github/jsdossier/jscomp:NodeAliasDetectionTest depends on @maven//:com_google_inject_guice in repository @maven which failed to fetch. no such package '@maven//': Error while obtaining the sha256 checksum of v1/https/jcenter.bintray.com/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/maven"): error=2, No such file or directory
ERROR: /Users/erikn/Documents/Programming/js-dossier/test/java/com/github/jsdossier/jscomp/BUILD:3:1: //test/java/com/github/jsdossier/jscomp:NodeAliasDetectionTest depends on @maven//:com_google_jimfs_jimfs in repository @maven which failed to fetch. no such package '@maven//': Error while obtaining the sha256 checksum of v1/https/jcenter.bintray.com/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/maven"): error=2, No such file or directory
ERROR: /Users/erikn/Documents/Programming/js-dossier/test/java/com/github/jsdossier/jscomp/BUILD:3:1: //test/java/com/github/jsdossier/jscomp:NodeAliasDetectionTest depends on @maven//:com_google_truth_truth in repository @maven which failed to fetch. no such package '@maven//': Error while obtaining the sha256 checksum of v1/https/jcenter.bintray.com/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/maven"): error=2, No such file or directory
ERROR: /Users/erikn/Documents/Programming/js-dossier/test/java/com/github/jsdossier/jscomp/BUILD:3:1: //test/java/com/github/jsdossier/jscomp:NodeAliasDetectionTest depends on @maven//:junit_junit in repository @maven which failed to fetch. no such package '@maven//': Error while obtaining the sha256 checksum of v1/https/jcenter.bintray.com/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/maven"): error=2, No such file or directory
ERROR: Analysis of target '//test/java/com/github/jsdossier/jscomp:NodeAliasDetectionTest' failed; build aborted: no such package '@maven//': Error while obtaining the sha256 checksum of v1/https/jcenter.bintray.com/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_erikn/4521f4523bde805bb0b44649cb6641b5/external/maven"): error=2, No such file or directory
INFO: Elapsed time: 8.723s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (23 packages loaded, 38 targets co\
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (23 packages loaded, 38 targets co\
nfigured)
```

Comment: Bash aliases will not work. Either fix the script or create a symlink

Comment: Just to note: this looks a couple of years old. So if it needs Python, it might need Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the problem was that I didn't have Python 2 installed any more.  After installing Python 2.7, the build script gets further, but it is now asking for other outdated things that don't exist (such as https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz).